# numexpr.interpreter module not found error in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, numpy, aws-lambda, langchain, numexpr

I created an aws lambda function that uses langchain to use AI. But I encountered a problem when I run the function like:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'numexpr.interpreter'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "276f3247-ec57-4e6d-b0ca-78855ff4e840",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I tried numexpr 2.8.5, 2.8.4, and 2.8.3 versions but it is not solved. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?